# Javascript filter array to itself. [object, object, object].filter(r => r)

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code:

```
let contentResps = responses.filter(resp => resp);
```

and I cannot figure out what it is doing. Responses is an array of Promises.

Comment: Perhaps it's trying to filter out null responses?

Comment: Are these promises fulfilled?

Comment: It might help to post mode code about `responses`.

Comment: `response.json()`

Answer (score 1):

This only keep thruthy values. For instance, if any of the responses is undefined, then it will only keep defined responses.